# Regex help - separating controller and action

Tags: regex

I need to separate the following url:

```
/myapp/public/controller/action
```

as $1 will be controller and $2 will be the action.

Here is the REGEX I´m using:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\.?([a-zA-Z\-_]+)?$
```

For some reason It is not separating, but putting the whole result in $1:

```
$1 = /myapp/public/controller/action
$2 = '' (empty)
```

PS: action is optional, as I may have /myapp/public/controller. In that case $2 shall be empty.

**[EDIT]**

The URL string may have the following formats:

```
/myapp/public/controller
/myapp/public/controller/action
/myapp/public/controller/action/param1
/myapp/public/controller/action/param1/param2/paramN
```

`$1` shall contain always the controller with full path
`$2` will receive the remaining (`action`, `action/param1`, `action/param1/param2/paramN`)

The controller will be always `myapp/public/controller`, where `myapp/public` is static and `controller` is the controller name that needs to go to $1 (the 3rd string).

At the extreme we can call `/myapp/public` and will be sending empty `''` controller that will default to index on the application.

PS: Sometimes things that seens simple are exactly the other way.... Thanks for the questions...

Comment: I will post in a edit.

Comment: How do you know when the action begins and the parameters start? Is the action always the thing after the forth slash?

Comment: Uh!! More info in the EDIT... I thought it would be a simple thing.... Thanks for asking...

Comment: `myapp\public` is static. `controller` is the name of controller and can change... corrected.

Comment: @Mendez, check out my update.

Comment: @stribizhev, added explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98036/discussion-between-mendez-and-ndn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(.+)\/([^\/]+)$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/eN0vL8/3)

---

With the new requirements:

```
^((?:\/[^\/]+){2,3})((?:\/[^\/]+)*)$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/eN0vL8/4)

Explaination:

- `(?:\/[^\/]+)` - matches a forward slash followed by characters, which are not forward slashes (like `/myapp`, `/public`, `/controller`, `/action` and so on)
- `{2,3}` - the controller consists of the first two or three such sequences. Two in the case when you are using the default index of the application.
- `*` - the remaining such sequences are part of the action

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the $1 shall be /myapp/public/controller not only controller.